# Is there any solution for "Uncaught Invalid Gregorian date" in JS when i am entering year for the first time?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, format

I am entering the date in input boxes separately, that means we can choose any field to give input for first time among day, month and year. But, when i am entering year for first time. It is giving me error saying "Uncaught Invalid Gregorian date". Any inputs on this from anyone?

```
new Date(yearValue, monthValue-1, dayValue);
```

Using above function for date selection.

I am passing the input value for year only as => 1900

Comment: Please add your code to your post

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that is causing this error. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to make a [mre].

Comment: Can't add more code for security reason.
@HereticMonkey@Platus updated my post.

Comment: If `new Date()` is given only one number value, it will use it as the number of milliseconds past 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Given a single string value, it will attempt to parse it as a full date. It could be failing at that, although without knowing anything more about the code than what you've shown, it's a guess.

Comment: @HereticMonkey—seems a reasonable guess, but doesn't explain the error message. Perhaps if "only year" is specified the OP is actually passing `1900, undefined, undefined`, but that just creates an invalid Date so maybe the message is coming from a framework, not JS.

Comment: @RobG I believe the same. There are some jquery lib is also used.
And its just showing error message on console window.

HereticMonkey Sorry, but its my office project level code. So, can't disclose more with respect to code.

Comment: Certainly you can recreate the situation without using the specific code? For instance, https://jsfiddle.net/sau5qk0b/ shows one possibility (without recreating the error). The idea is to generalize and simplify the code until you can reproduce the error. Up to you, of course, but otherwise, we'll have to close the question.